# Perform Git Clone of repository and run Maven test and display Extent Report via Shell script

Tags: linux, bash, git, maven, extentreports

I have a situation where I do not unfortunately have the ability to keep a Jenkins pipeline due to forces outside my control.  Since I have a linux server, the route to take in the interim will be to create a shell script that performs a git clone and runs the maven build script while also outputting the Extent report html file.  Maven and Git are already installed and configured on this machine as well.  This script will get kicked off by another deployment process.Below is a subset of the script in my JenkinsFile and I am looking to replicate it in a similar manner via bash script:

```
sh "mvn clean test -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2"
sh "mkdir -p TestResults"
sh "mv ./test-output/extent/AllTestCasesReport*.html TestResults/"
sh "mkdir -p TestResults/Screenshots"
sh "mv ./test-output/extent/*.png TestResults/Screenshots/ || error=true"

publishHTML([allowMissing: false,
            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
            keepAll: true,
            reportDir: 'TestResults',
            reportFiles: 'AllTestCasesReport*.html',
            reportName: 'UI_Test_Report',
            escapeUnderscores: 'false'])
//report url in jenkins
Report_URL = "https://jenkinsserverurl.mycompany.com:8443/job/myJob/job/UI_Weekend_Validation/UI_Test_Report/"
```

Below is my POM showing it running via maven surefire plugin:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.crystalfw</groupId>
    <artifactId>ui</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ui</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.2gis.winium</groupId>
            <artifactId>winium-webdriver</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0-1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-http-jdk-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-http-jdk-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng_xmls/testng_basic.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am not all too familiar with bash scripting, so I am wondering how I can replicate this type of logic in a bash script and be able to output the report to a specific directory, POST to a Microsoft teams channel via the curl POST seen above, and open the report via my browser locally.

Any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2` which JDK version and Maven are you using? why is there directory `test-output`? The usual output of tests etc will be done into `target/...`?

Comment: @khmaribaise it currently is going to a folder within the project called test-output.  I am using the maven surefire plugin to run test scripts.  The java version is 11, and the tls setting was not set to 1.2 before (not sure why) but the target server this will run on will have that so probably no need for it.  I believe via bash script on the linux server I can simply do a git clone, mvn test, write to log file etc but how about the delivery of the html file?  This process posts to a MS Teams channel with the Report_URL.  How can that be achieved via shell script on linux?

Comment: The `test-output` folder is usually created by a not correctly configured Eclipse test setup in relationship with TestNG... Can you give more details on the Maven verison, plugin version etc. because I fear you use outdated versions there... In Jenkins you will see results of your test in each by using junit/testng reporting plugin etc. without the need to publish the HTML report...

Comment: @khmarbaise currently in the framework an extent report is generated and goes to a test-output folder which is part of the parent project.  I believe I could change that to just go to "user.dir" System property to go to target instead?  Also have edited the post with the Maven POM attached.

Comment: Why aren't those deps defined as scope `test` and why using such an old version of maven-surefire-plugin ? (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) ..as I mentioned before using Jenkins produces a reporting on each build with the results... no need to create something with publishHtml...

Comment: @khmarbaise the point of the publish html plugin is because we are sharing a link to a report to a specific audience in an MS Teams channel.  Also, no longer using jenkins and having to do this via bash script route on our dedicated linux server.  I can upgrade the surefire version indeed.  Also the test scope, good point I'll change that for testng

Comment: You might take a look into https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/index.html that might already create what you need?